# How to check whether a username is in use?

Tags: rules

I'm currently trying to implement a function to check if a user already exists. I've read that this could be done by Rules whit the condition "Entity exists by property" but I can't find it anywhere. I've tried it with Rules 7.x-2.2 & Rules 7.x-2.3

Is this option still available or not? Or is it located in a other module?

it's related to this question: [How can I check whether a username is in use?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20436/how-can-i-check-whether-a-username-is-in-use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check this [issue](http://drupal.org/node/1777204) you will see that the condition has not yet been added to Rules. A patch is available if you wish to test it.

Comment: It's a website with different groups. Each group has the ability to add users to the system. This is done with a content node and the Rules action "create new entity". 
I could get the patch to work got a error on a entity function. But that patch helped me create a own module with a rule and some custom code.

Answer (score 2):

[Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/drupal-7.0) has a function to return a user object by username:

```
$user = user_load_by_name($name);
if(!$user){
    // User doesn't exist
} 
else {
    // User exists
}
```

[function user_load_by_name](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_load_by_name/7)

And a function to return a user object by email:

[function user_load_by_mail](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_load_by_mail/7)

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet and you can check whether the user selected name is available or not.

```
$name = 'user_selected_name';

$user = db_select('users', 'u')
    ->fields('u', array('name'))
    ->condition('u.name', $name, '=')
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAssoc();

    if($user) {
        print "user exists";
    }
    else {
        print "Name is available, You can take it.";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to check for the existence of a username for new users (who are registering), there *is* a module that implements that functionality, albeit in `7.x-1.x-dev` status... It's kind of hard to find because the name is a little complicated, but you might give it a try or even just look at the source code to get a feel for the way that module checks for username existence. It's called [Username originality AJAX check](http://drupal.org/project/username_check).